# How can I find the firewall program blocking access to SMB share

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

I have a very strange issue. Lately (less than 1-2 weeks at max), I cannot access my SMB share anymore from VLC on my Android phone.

I checked this behaviour with "FE File Explorer" on my iPad and it's the same.

So I tried to connect with the FE program and got the following sequence of entries within my Wireshark:

```
src:~.79, dest: ~.50 | 51089 -> 445 [SYN]
src:~.50, dest: ~.79 | 445 -> 51089 [SYN, ACK]
src:~.79, dest: ~.50 | 51089 -> 445 [ACK]
src:~.79, dest: ~.50 | 51089 -> 445 [FIN, ACK]
src:~.50, dest: ~.79 | 445 -> 51089 [ACK]
src:~.50, dest: ~.79 | 445 -> 51089 [RST, ACK]
```

From what I can understand after looking into this is that the last line means the connection has been reset. Which makes me think immediately about a firewall program.

However, I haven't changed any settings for Windows Firewall (it's off for the home network), and I did not install -knowingly- any firewall programs.

Is my assumption right? Is the last line an indication of a firewall? Or is it the networking service disconnecting the connection itself? And how can I figure out which program is interfering with the connection?

Thanks!

**EDIT1:**
When trying to access the SMB share from another computer, I do get this additional information:
After the 3rd ACK, I get:

```
SMB2 Negotiate Protocol Request
SMB2 Negotiate Protocol Response
SMB2 Session Setup Request, NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
SMB2 Session Setup Response, Error: STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED, NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE
SMB2 Session Setup Request, NTLMSSP_AUTH: User: other-pc\steven
SMB2 Session Setup Response, Error: STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE
```

What I glance from this is that it actually connects, and want to make a connection (but with the wrong username because the user is my-pc\steven).

But from my iPad I never got to see these SMB-fields. So there hasn't even been a protocol negotiation?

Did something change in Windows 7 in the past -let's say- month that could lead to this behaviour?

Comment: Based on your last edit, have you checked if somehow any update have been installed through automatic update in that time frame?

Comment: @ManuelFlorian: KB4480970 (9 jan), KB4480063 (9 jan), KB4483187 (22 dec), KB4480055 (9 jan). Thanks for the hint. I think KB4480970 is causing this issue!

Comment: @ManuelFlorian: uninstalling that one fixed it. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? [https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-kb4480960-and-kb4480970-updates-causing-network-and-license-problems/]

Comment: Ohhh I'm glad it worked. I copied and pasted as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last edit, have you checked if somehow any update have been installed through automatic update in that time frame?